# How to test entities which have not null foreign key constraints

Tags: java, database, hibernate, testing, spring-data-jpa

I have a dozen of tables like `Product`, `Category`, `Customer`, `Order`, ...
with `not null` relationships to one another. I created `ORM` and right now I am in the middle of tests.

However I find it pretty tedious, because in order to test for example `Order` entity which has to belong to `Customer` (namely perform `persist` operation) I have to create `Customer` instance as well. Lets go further: because `Order` cannot exist separately to `Product` I have to create `Product` and add it to `Order`. `Product` has to be in some `Category`, and so on. So you can see a chain of mandatory relationships, which makes testing individual entity very difficult.

Natural solution would be to defer constraint check to commit (Oracle):

```sql
alter session set constraints=deferred;
```

However I found a piece of information that `Hibernate` doesn't care of deferring ([support for deferred constraint](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2248)).

Does it mean, that persistence testing has to be so problematic or I can do it better/different?

I believe that db constraints are sacred, so resigning from them, because hibernate does not support it sounds bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can create factories for test purposes. Their job is to create a graph of objects that are valid. Such class can be used in any kind of testing (not only the repositories):

```
ProductFactory.withType(...).withOtherImportantOption(...).create()
```

Such factory could leverage [randomization](http://qala.io/blog/randomized-testing.html) if you wish, but it's not mandatory. Though some amount of randomization will have to be introduced for fields with unique constraints.

PS: not satisfying FK seems like a wrong path - you'll eventually need tests that persist many objects, maybe even commit transactions. And you may also want to test cascades.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create your test database prepopulated with a bunch of test data.

You can define test data in a file named `import.sql`, or specified via `javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source`, and it will be automatically loaded by the schema export tool.

UPDATE: To be clear, you only need a couple of rows of test data in each table, that you'll use in order to set up valid references from the objects you're testing.

For example, if you want to test persisting a `Book`, you would write:

```
Book b = new Book();
b.setTitle("Feersum Endjin");
b.setAuthor( em.getReference(Author.class, AUTHOR_ID) );
em.persist(b);
```

Where `AUTHOR_ID` is the id of a row of test data.

This is a lot better, IMO, than writing tests that work with objects in an inconsistent state (i.e. with null attributes) and test data that violates the database constraints.

Comment: Creating additional sql scripts isn't very convenient: 1) you have to duplicate how you persist objects (JPA _and_ SQL), so if some field changes - you'll have to update more than just the mapping. 2) Tests are more readable when the data they use is explicitly written in the test 3) At some point the number of tests will be so large that the amount of test data in the SQL script will be hard to manage. 4) and so on.. Here it's all summed up: http://qala.io/blog/test-data-management.html

Comment: @Gavin King I could sure (even I did that for other tests), but I wanted to test persisting instead of fetching data from database.

Comment: @jwpol I've updated the post to explain more fully what I mean. I'm saying that you can use `getReference()` to set up valid refs to pre-loaded test data from the objects you're testing. Not that all your test entities are defined in the script.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev If the schema of your domain model changes, your code that defines test entities will necessarily change, whether that code is written in Java, or in SQL. For the eleventy-billionth time: there's nothing wrong with using SQL together with Hibernate.

Comment: "_code that defines test entities will necessarily change_" - sure, but you'd probably have to change several places - not all the tests that work with those test entities. With SQL you don't have such luxury. If a column changes - you'll have to update all the INSERT statements. I see that you updated your answer to point out that only several of such INSERT statements are required. But I can't see how you can write nice looking tests with such approach, especially when you get to write higher-level tests. Though it would probably suffice to test Repositories I guess..

Comment: "_there's nothing wrong with using SQL together with Hibernate_" - but there's something wrong if you _duplicate_ persistence logic both in SQL _and_ in Repository (be it a JDBC Repo or Hibernate Repo - it doesn't really matter).

Comment: @Gavin King, I get it now, makes sense thanks for the update, I'll definitely try it out

Comment: However I agree with @Stanislav Bashkyrtsev, we'll have to change the code in several places, whenever ORM or tables definition changes, populating data using SQL as well. For my purpose I can afford it nevertheless, my model is not extremely big.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JPA, then your repositories are tested automatically. If you really need to, then have a look [here](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-data-jpa-test/).

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Unfortunately not. My question is related to problematic testing of entities which have mandatory relationships to one another. Persisting them violates integrity constraints, so I'd like to defer a check to commit or use any other technique which allows to test (persist) particular entities without getting rid of the constraints itself.

Comment: so I'm more correct assuming you could use something like this? https://thorben-janssen.com/automatically-validate-entities-with-hibernate-validator/